# Get categories and then posts for custom post type

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, taxonomy, custom-taxonomy

Thanks all for reading my post..

I am using WPLMS theme and custom post type is registered as 'Course'

I am getting all post's with this code:

```
$args = array(
'orderby'          => 'date',
'order'            => 'DESC',
'post_type'        => 'course',
'post_status'      => 'publish',
'suppress_filters' => true
```

I want to get all categories and then posts from each category.

Example: Category name : education and get all posts from education, I want to get all the categories name and then their respective post, Or get all category names and then posts but posts must have their category name as well.

I hope it will work's.

Thanks for your help in advance

Answer (score 0):

This code will list all the posts according to categories:

```
 $categories = get_terms( 'category' );
        foreach ($categories as $key => $value) {
            $args = array(
        'posts_per_page'   => -1,
        'offset'           => 0,
        'category'         => $value->term_id, // tells category id
        'post_type'        => 'course',
        'post_status'      => 'publish',
        'suppress_filters' => true 
        );
        $posts_array = get_posts( $args ); 
        echo "<pre>{$value->name}"; 
        print_r($posts_array);
        echo "</pre>";
}
```